# cs50 week 4 filter, my code does not return errors, however the sum of values for the blur and edges functions are incorrect

Tags: c, cs50

Blur
There are a number of ways to create the effect of blurring or softening an image. For this problem, we’ll use the “box blur,” which works by taking each pixel and, for each color value, giving it a new value by averaging the color values of neighboring pixels.

Consider the following grid of pixels, where we’ve numbered each pixel.

a grid of pixels
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXXuN.png)

The new value of each pixel would be the average of the values of all of the pixels that are within 1 row and column of the original pixel (forming a 3x3 box). For example, each of the color values for pixel 6 would be obtained by averaging the original color values of pixels 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, and 11 (note that pixel 6 itself is included in the average). Likewise, the color values for pixel 11 would be be obtained by averaging the color values of pixels 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15 and 16.

For a pixel along the edge or corner, like pixel 15, we would still look for all pixels within 1 row and column: in this case, pixels 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, and 16.

Edges
In artificial intelligence algorithms for image processing, it is often useful to detect edges in an image: lines in the image that create a boundary between one object and another. One way to achieve this effect is by applying the Sobel operator to the image.

Like image blurring, edge detection also works by taking each pixel, and modifying it based on the 3x3 grid of pixels that surrounds that pixel. But instead of just taking the average of the nine pixels, the Sobel operator computes the new value of each pixel by taking a weighted sum of the values for the surrounding pixels. And since edges between objects could take place in both a vertical and a horizontal direction, you’ll actually compute two weighted sums: one for detecting edges in the x direction, and one for detecting edges in the y direction. In particular, you’ll use the following two “kernels”:

Sobel kernels
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4n8w.png)

How to interpret these kernels? In short, for each of the three color values for each pixel, we’ll compute two values Gx and Gy. To compute Gx for the red channel value of a pixel, for instance, we’ll take the original red values for the nine pixels that form a 3x3 box around the pixel, multiply them each by the corresponding value in the Gx kernel, and take the sum of the resulting values.

Why these particular values for the kernel? In the Gx direction, for instance, we’re multiplying the pixels to the right of the target pixel by a positive number, and multiplying the pixels to the left of the target pixel by a negative number. When we take the sum, if the pixels on the right are a similar color to the pixels on the left, the result will be close to 0 (the numbers cancel out). But if the pixels on the right are very different from the pixels on the left, then the resulting value will be very positive or very negative, indicating a change in color that likely is the result of a boundary between objects. And a similar argument holds true for calculating edges in the y direction.

Using these kernels, we can generate a Gx and Gy value for each of the red, green, and blue channels for a pixel. But each channel can only take on one value, not two: so we need some way to combine Gx and Gy into a single value. The Sobel filter algorithm combines Gx and Gy into a final value by calculating the square root of Gx^2 + Gy^2. And since channel values can only take on integer values from 0 to 255, be sure the resulting value is rounded to the nearest integer and capped at 255!

And what about handling pixels at the edge, or in the corner of the image? There are many ways to handle pixels at the edge, but for the purposes of this problem, we’ll ask you to treat the image as if there was a 1 pixel solid black border around the edge of the image: therefore, trying to access a pixel past the edge of the image should be treated as a solid black pixel (values of 0 for each of red, green, and blue). This will effectively ignore those pixels from our calculations of Gx and Gy.

However, when I run my code it does not return the correct values. Im not very sure what went wrong in my code and i cant accurately determine the problem as cs50 does not highlight which part went wrong.

```
void calculateAverage(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int i, int j) {
    int sumR = 0;
    int sumG = 0;
    int sumB = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int row = i - 1; row <= i + 1; row++) {
        for (int col = j - 1; col <= j + 1; col++) {
            // Check if the indices are within bounds
            if (row >= 0 && row < height && col >= 0 && col < width) {
                sumR += image[row][col].rgbtRed;
                sumG += image[row][col].rgbtGreen;
                sumB += image[row][col].rgbtBlue;
                count++;

            }
        }
    }
    // Avoid division by zero
    if (count > 0) {
        image[i][j].rgbtRed = sumR / count;
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sumG / count;
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = sumB / count;

    }
}

// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            calculateAverage(height, width, image, i, j);
        }
    }
    return;
}

int gxgy(int narray[3][3])
{
    int gx[][3] = {
        {-1, 0, 1},
        {-2, 0, 2},
        {-1, 0, 1}};

    int gxsum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            gxsum += narray[i][j] * gx[i][j];
        }
    }

    int gy[][3] = {
    {-1, -2, -1},
    {0, 0, 0},
    {1, 2, 1}};

    int gysum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            gysum += narray[i][j] * gy[i][j];
        }
    }

    double gradientMagnitude = sqrt(pow(gxsum, 2) + pow(gysum, 2));
    int result = gradientMagnitude + 0.5;
    return (result > 255) ? 255 : result;
}

void edgedetection(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int i, int j)
{
    int garry[3][3];
    int rarry[3][3];
    int barry[3][3];

    for (int row = i - 1, ni = 0; row <= i + 1; row++, ni++) {
        for (int col = j - 1, nj = 0; col <= j + 1; col++, nj++) {
            // Check if the neighbor is within bounds
            if (row >= 0 && row < height && col >= 0 && col < width) {
                garry[ni][nj] = image[row][col].rgbtRed;
                rarry[ni][nj] = image[row][col].rgbtGreen;
                barry[ni][nj] = image[row][col].rgbtBlue;
            } else {
                garry[ni][nj] = 0;
                rarry[ni][nj] = 0;
                barry[ni][nj] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    image[i][j].rgbtRed = gxgy(rarry);
    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = gxgy(garry);
    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = gxgy(barry);
}

// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            edgedetection(height, width, image, i, j);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: You need to read from the original image and write the results to a copy of the image otherwise you're reading modified values as you go. I assume that's the issue you're having since you haven't actually asked a question, you've just copy/pasted the task description. Be specific about what you're asking for help with.

Comment: `image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sumR / (double)count);` may also help if you find your results are off by a small amount.

Comment: `"Im not very sure what went wrong in my code and i cant accurately determine the problem as cs50 does not highlight which part went wrong."` - The program `check50` provided by CS50 will tell you whether it is the `blur` function or the `edges` function that is failing. If you follow the link provided by `check50`, it will also tell you which pixel is failing, i.e. whether it is a middle pixel or a corner pixel, and also which one. Please [edit] the question to add this important information.